# How to use FormControl with ngComponentOutlet - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ng-component-outlet

I'm trying to use dynamic component loading with formControl but it's not affecting my host formGroup.

Tried those options:

Template:

option 1 - not working:

```
 <div [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="getComponent()" [formControlName]="getFormControlName()"></ng-container>
 </div>
```

option 2 - not working:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="getComponent()" [formControl]="getFormControl()"></ng-container>
</div>
```

option 3 - working:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <my-dynamic-component [formControl]="dynamicFormControl"></my-dynamic-component>
</div>
```

Component functions:

getComponent: return dynamic component (that supports the use of reactiveForm)

getFormControlName: return formControl name. return string

getFormControl: return formControl object. FormControl

Someone knows what i should do? this is possible?

Check out that example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8sdrm?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you prepare stackblitz example?

Comment: @yurzui check out that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8sdrm?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @yurzui any answer/follow up ?

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://medium.com/thekiba/dynamic-component-rendering-in-angular-with-auto-data-binding-22dd340a4142

Comment: Any solution for add formControl in ngComponentOutlet?